# Trigger change event after click event in alpine.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

In the following example, when clicking on the select element and changing the value, the textarea value is set to empty.

I also have buttons that change the select value, but this does not trigger the change event and set the textarea value to empty.

```
<div x-data="{ select : 1, textarea : 'test' }">
    <div>
        <button x-on:click="select = 1">One</button>
        <button x-on:click="select = 2">Two</button>
        <button x-on:click="select = 3">Three</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <select name="test" x-model="select" x-on:change="textarea = ''">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <textarea name="foobar" x-model="textarea">test</textarea>    
</div>
```

I can get this working by updating the click events on each button, like the following.

```
<button x-on:click="select = 1; textarea = ''">One</button>
```

Is there any way to trigger the change event on the select, regardless of whether it's triggered by the button or directly changing the select value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x-model` will update the value without triggering a "change" event.

In your case, I assume you want "whenever `select` changes, reset textarea value to `''`".

Which you can do using `x-init` and `$watch('select', () => { textarea = '' })`. As a bonus you don't need the `x-on:change="textarea = ''"` on the `<select>` any more.

Full example would be:

```html
<div
  x-data="{ select : 1, textarea : 'test' }"
  x-init="$watch('select', () => { textarea = '' })"
>
    <div>
        <button x-on:click="select = 1">One</button>
        <button x-on:click="select = 2">Two</button>
        <button x-on:click="select = 3">Three</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <select name="test" x-model="select">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <textarea name="foobar" x-model="textarea">test</textarea>    
</div>
```